# Plot one line per 1 second java

Tags: java, swing

I have a linked list with the coordinates of points. I want to plot one line per second. Here is the function for plotting:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    for (Line line : lines) {
        g.drawLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: Do you want to slow down this iteration so that you execute `g.drawLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)` once per second?

Comment: Yes, I say it clearly: Plot one line per 1 second

Answer (score 3):

I think this'll be helpful,

```
 int i = 0;
 Timer timer = new Timer(1000, null);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);

    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(i < lines.length){
                Line line = lines[i];
                g.drawLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);
                i++;
            }else{
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
```

Comment: 1+ for the Timer. All Swing updates should be executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new Thread and wait for 1000 miliseconds:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Line line : lines) {
                g.drawLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Down-vote from me. You are creating the thread within the for-each loop, thus rendering your sleeping redundant. Maybe take slightly longer to answer and get it right first time?

Comment: Sorry. Copy-paste problem.

Comment: @Duncan Sorry. I've changed it. Was in a hurry.

Comment: See also [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: 1-, Don't use a Thread. Swing updates should be done on the EDT. Use a Swing Timer.